# Pink and Blue artefacts appearing in the notification centre

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, display, graphics

Hi I just got the new MacBook and installed Mac OS sierra on it.

I keep coming across an issue whereby there are pink and blue pixelated diagonal lines appearing in the notification centre and when I try to screenshot them they go away.

Attached is an image I took with my iPhone as was not working
[image: screenshoting]

Comment: got the exact same issue on my macbook 2016

Comment: @kritop updated to sierra?

Comment: yes, have similar artifacts in the safari tab bar from time to time

Comment: @kritop just wondering if the update caused this, but I didn't use it long enough before the update to know. Did u have the issue before the update? Last time I had something similar was with my 2011 MacBook Pro when the logic board had to be replaced

Comment: i am certain it wasn't there before, i would noticed it in safari which i use daily. i also encounter this problem: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250073/macbook-2016-randomly-turns-black-every-couple-of-minutes-with-external-display but already before sierra

Comment: @kritop did u document the issue and submit feedback? I did. I also raised a support ticket which got taken down, this tell me that they are treating it as a sierra bug, but idk just an assumption

Comment: i didn't do anything about it yet.

Answer (score -1):

I do have exactly the same artefacts on MacBook 2016 1.2 Ghz.
They appearing when there's some window under the notification centre. Can be seen on FaceTime app window sometime as well.

Looks like a software/driver issue so far.

Update: 
Tried it with clean install of El Capitan — it's not there, everything is ok. So it is a Sierra bug. Reported it to Apple via Bug Reporter as a 10.12 bug.

Comment: Your answer is just conjecture at this point. Can you improve it with some supporting evidence of the claim it's "a software/driver issue so far"?

Comment: Have you tried raising the issue with apple support? The more of us that do this the better it is as it will bring the issue to the forefront.