# MacBook 2016 randomly turns black every couple of minutes with external Display attached

Tags: macbook-pro, hdmi

It seems like a reset and is happening a dozen times per hour. It happen via HDMI on my Dell U3415W and on a low resolution projector (1024x768px), i used the original Apple adapter but also the Minix.

Sometimes when it returns i have heavy artifacts on the display and have to unplug/plug the hdmi again for normal operation.

Comment: This shouldn't be happening. Did you contact Apple about this? This might be a defect with the onboard or external graphic card.

Comment: not yet, will try that and update this post

Comment: I have had this problem with 2 different MacBook 2016's and numerous Dell monitors, all connected by HDMI via Apple's Digital Multiport Adapter.

Comment: I've updated to Sierra 10.12.3 and the problem remains.
It goes black even more often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed with macOS Sierra 10.12.2 (16C679)